# Correlated subqueries using SQL

Tags: mysql

I just started coding using sql. This is an example of correlated- subquery I an struggling with; Can anyone please explain in layman terms whats going on here:

```
SELECT id
FROM flights AS f
WHERE distance > (SELECT AVG(distance)
                  FROM flights
                  WHERE carrier = f.carrier);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns all flights, where the distance is bigger than average distance of that particular carrier.

An example:

```
id flight     carrier   distance
 1 Brussels   Swiss     200
 2 New York   Swiss     2000
 3 Berlin     Lufthansa 300
 4 London     Lufthansa 400
```

average distance of Swiss is 1100 and of Lufthansa is 350

And your query returns:

```
2
4
```

Flight 2 is of carrier Swiss and its distance 2000 is bigger than the average distance of Swiss with 1100.

Flight 4 is of carrier Lufthansa and its distance 400 is bigger than the average distance of Lufthansa with 350.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is semantically identical to the following, which (personally) I find easier to read. (I suspect it's fractionally faster too)...

```
SELECT id 
  FROM flights g
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT carrier
            , AVG(distance) avg_distance
        GROUP
           BY carrier
     ) x
    ON x.carrier = f.carrier
   AND x.distance > avg_distance;
```

Comment: which one do you think is faster? your query or the one I wrote?

Comment: I can understand the query you wrote. Thanks